# TypeSCript Error: Cant Assign certain types to variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, boolean, undefined

I have defined the type of the following variables as:

```
let isDisabled: boolean | undefined | null;
let isPrivate: boolean | undefined | null;
```

when I try doing this:

```
isDisabled = null;
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

I get the same error when I try to set to undefined.

I have also tried to declare the variables as

```
let isDisabled: Maybe<boolean> | undefined;
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Note: this happens when TypeScript is being compiled to JS

Comment: It seems to be valid TypeScript and functioning in 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAlgzgIrAhgI1AEwFwWQex6RAOwgB8IBXQtEAMykJDVIkPOGAG4AoWBGFdBAC8LNpy4BjHIRj4QAOmA4A5gApeSVIwCUQA

Comment: Ha, seems it’s valid TypeScript (this is part of a react code) so I’m not sure if the problem is coming from React.

Comment: There is no error in ts playground. Please share full example with error

Answer (score 0):

boolean are defined only by **True;** or **False;** ??

Even when you try to assign something to a var, you should avoid the default like "null" try using other keywords ...

Comment: He used a union type, so he can assign multiple different types

Comment: In this instance, I have to explicitly check if these variables are True/False, Null or Undefined because they can be sent in any of those types. Plus, this is a test file so I’m trying to write tests for different scenarios.

Comment: That is true, but error says "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'".